# Logstash type conversion not working in single mutate filter

Tags: filter, logstash, dplyr

Below is my mutate filter configuration, where caller and callee data is in below format. Its not working as both caller and callee data is set to 0 on type conversion. Conversion is working fine when I used separate mutate filter for type conversion. Why my first configuration is not working ?

```
"caller":"caller:123"
"callee":"callee:123"

mutate {
          gsub => [
                   #regex to remove : and every thing before it 
                   "caller", "^[^:]*:", "",                        
                   "callee","^[^:]*:", ""
                  ]
          convert => { 
                     #type conversion from string to integer 
                       "caller" => "integer"
                       "callee" => "integer"                             
                     }                                              
        }
```

Type conversion is working fine with two separate mutate filters are used

```
      mutate {
              gsub => [
                       #regex to remove : and every thing before it 
                       "caller", "^[^:]*:", "",                        
                       "callee","^[^:]*:", ""
                      ]
       } 

           mutate {
                     convert => { "caller" => "integer"
                                  "callee"=>  "integer" 
                                 } 

                   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, from the source code, the convert operation is called before the gsub operation.

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-mutate/blob/d8936feaa5c7141f96fdfbf1120f23ecdc816275/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb#L218:

```
  def filter(event)
    ...
    convert(event) if @convert
    gsub(event) if @gsub
```